# how to send TWO strings with arduino pubsubclient library - getting invalid operand error

Tags: c++, arduino, mqtt, publish-subscribe

probably a simple enough thing - so much so I thought it would be worth asking.

I'm familiar with the [pubsub mqtt client library](https://github.com/knolleary/pubsubclient) from the hirotasker port for Spark/Particle devices. I am trying to use it now on an arduino and hitting a bit of a stumbing block. I'm trying to do this:

`client.publish("telemetry", String1 + "confidence=" + String2);`

I can't send a string like I can with for example [the arduino-mqtt library](https://github.com/256dpi/arduino-mqtt/), I get errors about 'no known conversion' or candidate expects 3 arguments and only 2 povided etc.

So I modify it to:

`client.publish("telemetry", String1.c_str() + "confidence=" + String2.c_str());`

but that's a no go either

> error: invalid operands of types 'const char*' and 'const char [12]' to binary 'operator+'
> client.publish("telemetry", String1.c_str() + "confidence=" + String2.c_str));

Comment: `String1.c_str() + "confidence=" + String2.c_str()` -- This was never going to work, regardless of what you are developing on.  You are adding character pointers, not strings.  Show us the function prototype of `publish`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the API-Documentation of the publish-function:

https://pubsubclient.knolleary.net/api#publish

It expects a `char[]` for the topic and a `char[]` for the message. As your error message states, you are trying to concatenate three `char[]` with the +-operator, which is not possible.
One way is to use a temporary String-Object for the character array `"confidence="`.

```
String tmp = String1 + String("confidence=") + String2;
```

To get the `char[]` behind the String-Object you can use `tmp.c_str()`.

Comment: Thanks. Stupid of me not to think of this. Thank you that did the trick! Feeling daft and grateful at once.